# Make VS 2012 the default exe for .cs, .config, etc files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

So I have both VS 2010 and 2012 installed, and we are mostly migrated to 2012 now.  However, the default association for .cs files, and .config files, etc is still VS2010.  So, if I double-click on a loose .cs file, or a loose, .config file, etc, VS2010 opens.

I know how to change file associations piecemeal,  but is there a way to have Visual Studio migrate the default exe for all vs file types over to 2012?

BTW:  The solution detection stuff is working fine -- a 2012 solution goes to 2012, and a 2010 to 2010 -- it's all the other individual file types that are still associated with 2010.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of ways to accomplish this, but I recommend doing this within Visual Studio 2012:

`Tools > Options > Environment > General > Manage File Associations`

[image]

---

***Alternative Solution:***

Another way would be right clicking on the file in File Explorer, then using `Choose default program...`

[image]
[image]

Comment: D'oh!  I was right in that options dialog before I posted, and didn't even notice the button (I was looking for something in the tree!  Thanks Dom!

Comment: Sure thing, glad I could help! Don't worry, I overlooked it initially too...very easy to miss!